# How to send an email with excel file as attachment in angular-node app

Tags: node.js, excel, angular, typescript

I am working on angular (frontend) and node ( backend). I want to send an email using sendgrid , With excel file as attachment. I followed the app as reference [demo app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-export-xlsx) .Instead of downloading the excel, I want the same file to be sent as email attachment.

Note : In the backend I use nodejs, I am not sure how to pass the file with  API to node.js, I can send email in nodejs code.

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can make an http post request in the node api back-end and pass the file. Do post using headers as Multipart form request.

Multipart form request helps you to make the node js api pass the excel sheet generated on the front end.

In your email service add the http service call to the backend. And make the service pass the file in it

Check this link out for more details

https://blog.jscrambler.com/implementing-file-upload-using-node-and-angular/

Comment: Thanks Hitesh, can you explain me more how to do this ? I am new to this technology